# Can't show data dataGrid when using datasource JSON [DEVEXTREME ANGULARJS]

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, json, devexpress, devextreme

When I'm bind using angularjs it's work properly but when using DevExtreme it's not work

This is function getAll

```
//To Get All Records
function GetAllEntry() {
    var promiseGet = GetAllEntryService.GetAllEntry();
    promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.GetAllEntry = pl.data },
        function (errorPl) {
           console.log('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
        });
}
```

this table bind using angularJS

```html
<tbody ng-repeat="entry in GetAllEntry">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="">
    </td>
    <td>{{ entry.TICKET_NUMBER }}</td>
    <td>{{ entry.REQUESTER }}</td>
    <td>{{ entry.CATEGORY }}</td>
    <td>{{ entry.SUBCATEGORY }}</td>
    <td>{{ entry.SUBJECT }}</td>
    <td>{{ entry.BODY }}</td>
    <td>{{ entry.FILE_NAME }}</td>
    <td>{{ entry.ASSIGNED_TO }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

That its working properly good!

But When using devExtreme:

```
$scope.dataGridOptions = {
    dataSource: {
        store: GetAllEntry()
    },
        columns: ['TICKET_NUMBER', 'REQUESTER', 'CATEGORY', 'SUBCATEGORY', 'SUBJECT', 'BODY', 'FILE_NAME', 'ASSIGNED_TO']
    };
```

in HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="gridContainer" dx-data-grid="dataGridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

It's not showing my data? What code I'm missing add to this project?

reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.2.4/js/dx.webappjs.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.2.4/css/dx.common.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.2.4/css/dx.light.css" />
```